# Calculating with bound generics

Tags: java, generics

I am stuck with type save programming. I tryed to make a universal multiply method. But Arithmetic operators cannot be applied to my generic Types.
Therefore I extended My generic to Integer. Here is an Example of my Code:

```
 public class Calculator<V extends Integer> {

  public <V extends Integer> V multiply(V value1, V value2) {
    return value1 * value2;
  }
}
```

I already tried to discover my mistake at the literature "Java ist auch eine Insel" and I've searched the Web. Well I am sure that some of you can fix this problem single handy never the less i am thankful for your help.

Comment: To get the `int` value from an `Integer` object, use [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29).

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the problem? What is that part that is written in German? What are you trying to achieve? That class can only be used with `Integer`, so it isn't universal.

Comment: Well the german part is a book...I wrote that its literature. the Integer part is a example sherlok. Furthermore the Problem is quite clear. Also I said that i tryed to find my mistake, how would I be able to tell you my mistake while im still searching for it. Try to be more constructive next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you've defined a type-parameter `<V extends Integer>` on a class-level, which is fine, unless you've re-defined a method-scoped type-parameter `<V extends Integer>`. The method-scoped type-parameter *hides* the class-scoped one and this is one of your mistakes here.

Futhermore, `<V extends Integer>` doesn't make much sense for various reasons:

As `Integer` is a `final` class, there's no point of talking about "a *possible* subtype of `Integer`, called `V`" and also, the multiplication operator (`*`) works only for numeric types and their wrappers (and since there's no evidence that `V` is such, the compilation hence fails).

Having just:

```
public class Calculator {
    public Integer multiply(Integer value1, Integer value2) {
      return value1 * value2;
    }
}
```

will compile fine, because now the compiler will *know* that `value1` and `value2` can be auto unboxed from `Integer` to `int` and the multiply operator could be correctly applied.

To summarize, it's not that easy to create a `Calculator` class around some generic type (mostly because of the strict range of types that the numeric operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, etc. work with).

Answer (score 0):

`<V extends Integer>` doesn't make any sense because Integer is final class [see javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) which means you can't extend from it. You can use [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) as a superclass for your generic and get the values  using `.floatValue()` to multiply those. To keep it even more universal - use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead of all these types (no generics required, just some unboxing/casting)